# WindowsAzure ACS toolkitfor iOS (iPhone) - Facebook identity provider

Tags: iphone, ios, azure, acs

Is there a way to configure the Azure toolkit to use the mobile version of the Facebook login page on iPhone when Facebook is identity provider? Currently the toolkit uses the desktop web page, which makes it a bit unusable...

**Edit**

See [the same error on the Windows Azure Development forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/0c1ec319-bd69-4b76-a27a-fe708a6f9035).

Answer (score 1):

This actually has nothing to do with the toolkit, and frankly not even with the ACS implementation for FaceBook sign-in protocol. Over which, we currently do not have control. And would prefer to continue using ACS like that.

It is more the FaceBook themselves to appropriately chose which login page to show, based on user device, like they do for their site.

What I would give a try is to edit my FaceBook Application, and add my ACS namespace also at the mobile web app sectin, just to check the result:

[image]

Comment: That is interesting... We will give it a try!

Comment: We have try this possibility, but unfortunately Facebook still shows the standard desktop login page. In advanced app setting we also found the switch web/desktop app but also this option does not led to wanted result.

Answer (score 0):

Arwind will follow up with you on [Azure ACS for the iOS - is there any support? Problems with Facebook on iPhone](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/0c1ec319-bd69-4b76-a27a-fe708a6f9035).

Please refer to the thread above to see whether it helps.

Comment: Hi, that would be good if we find an answer to that - I think almost everybody who uses the Facebook as identity provider will need that...